# Send env to a makefile target

Tags: linux, bash, git, environment-variables, makefile

I am trying to set an env var which is git sha1 commit for a makefile target. I am setting a lot of env vars and only this fails with no such file or directory error. I am hell confused. Please help me pass this as env var to my makefile target. This is what I do in the beginning of my Makefile.

```
SHA1 := $(shell git log | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')
BUILD_STAMP := $(shell date +%s)
export SHA1
export BUILD_STAMP
```

And one of the makefile targets have like this.

```
target: dep-target
     env \
              VAR1=$(VAR1) \
              GIT_SHA1=$(SHA1) \
     my-command for the target
```

This fails with

```
env: a6d23d14b0fbb613e567cc647ebfe2808ce47af1: No such file or directory
```

Please help me set this as env var.

Comment: If you find the answer to your question below, then mark it as "accepted" by clicking the gray tick beside it.

Comment: Does SHA1's value have a space in it?

Answer (score 3):

```
 VAR1=$(VAR1)
 GIT_SHA1=$(SHA1)
```

The round braces, parentheses, used with a `$` just before them in this way will cause the text between the parentheses to be sent to Bash as a command line to try to execute.

Replace with curly braces instead, i.e. `GIT_SHA1=${SHA1}` and you will get the intended variable assignment instead.

Comment: Are you sure? Make should do its variable replacement first (and it sees $() as a variable replacement) and THEN bash won't see any $() because Make replaced them first.

Comment: I assume, based on "No such file of directory" that I am right.

Comment: You might notice that A) the file or directory that wasn't found is called `a6d23d14b0fbb613e567cc647ebfe2808ce47af1`, not `SHA1`, and B) that the message was printed by `env`, not `bash`.

Comment: I assume `SHA1 := $(shell git log | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')` sets the variable to that value, and the fact that env prints it implies for me that env was run via Bash ( or "system()" ).

Comment: if `$(...)` meant "send this to bash as a command line to try to execute" then `$(SHA1)` would try to execute the command `SHA1` which would print an error saying the command `SHA1` was not found. What happens if you type `SHA1` in your terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment on @Hannu's wrong answer (curly and round parenthesis are equivalent in Make).

To debug this sort of thing, create a separate short Makefile and try things like this:

```
SHA1 := $(shell git log | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')
all:
        echo "$(SHA1)"
```

This shows what is happening is SHA1 gets assigned the entire first line of git log output, not just the SHA, and that includes spaces. The expanded env command would then have invalid syntax.

In this case, the dollar sign in the awk command needs to be doubled (print $$2) so that expands to a literal dollar sign and not as the empty variable $(2).

Comment: `(curly and round parenthesis are equivalent in Make).`  Think hard! What are you writing *at that very spot* in the makefile?

Comment: @Hannu A variable expansion?